# Laravel Scheduled Tasks Stopped Running at Midnight

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler, laravel-horizon

We have two identical Laravel environments, running the exact same configuration even the same Laravel app build.

The backend Laravel worker app has two instances, so we use `onOneServer()` for each task. The workers are also running Horizon queue.

At midnight a few nights ago UTC, the production workers stopped running some tasks, while the dev workers did not. The day after at midnight it started again, then two days later at midnight it stopped.

Can Horizon usage (production has much more than dev) have any impact on locking the tasks to one worker preventing it from even starting?

Comment: Are you using `withoutOverlapping`? And are you sure none of the jobs are stuck?

Comment: I wasn't sure if `withoutOverlapping` would cause any conflicts with `onOneServer` but I have tested it and there seems to be no change. I'm not sure how to check if some of the tasks are stuck, it only seems to affect some of the longer running tasks.